# Can I use sforce.one.createRecord() and programmatically set one of the fields on the create page?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I have a custom visualforce page that displays some account info. The page has a "New Contact" button that does this:

> sforce.one.createRecord('Contact');

This works great.  However, I would like for the Account lookup field on the new contact page to be pre-populated with the Account the user is viewing.  Is this possible in SF1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Summer '17 Release Notes - [Prepopulate Fields on a Record Create Panel](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_defaultfieldvalues.htm)

> Speed up record creation with prepopulated field values. The sforce.one.createRecord function now includes `defaultFieldValues` (optional) so you can define fields on a record create panel, including fields not displayed on the panel. This change applies to Lightning Experience and the Salesforce1 mobile browser app.
>
> Users must have create access to prepopulated fields. Errors during saving that are caused by field access limitations do not display error messages.

So `defaultFieldValues` will become the official supported mechanism to preset fields with `sforce.one.createRecord`.

Answer (score 3):

The kind of URL hacking that works in Salesforce will not work in Salesforce1.  In order to do pre-fill field values in Salesforce1, you would need another Visualforce page.  The new page would be passed the ID of the current account as a parameter and use that to set class fields as needed.

Comment: He can't add any code to the button to pass the AccountID as the Related Account field in SF1?

Comment: I've seen it said in various places (can't find any just now) that old-style Salesforce URL hacking will not work in Salesforce1.  Certainly my limited attempts at it have not worked.  If there is a way to do this that doesn't require the creation of a VF page, I'd love to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielBallinger's answer is correct. I just want to extend it by an example and show you the most likely pitfalls trying to make it work. Plain and simple, you can use it like this one-liner:

```
sforce.one.createRecord('Contact',null,{ 
    AccountId : "0010Y000007uaVI",  
});
```

**Caution 1:**

The this feature from Summer'17 works only if you put your Visualforce Page to API v40.0 or higher.

**Caution 2:**

Objectnames and Fieldnames are CASE-SENSITiVE! So `contact` is not `Contact` and only `Contact` is correct