# Create record in Lightning with populated fields

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, navigation, lightning-ready

Is there a way to use the sforce.one.createRecord to create an Opportunity and fill in fields with data? In Salesforce Classic this was accomplished by adding parameters to the url (ex: ?name=foo).

Has Salesforce given a way to do this in Lightning?

Comment: Potential duplicate of  [Can I use sforce.one.createRecord() and programmatically set one of the fields on the create page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/64850/102)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

URL hacks are not supported in Lightning Experience. The best way to prepopulate fields in Lightning Experience is to use actions.

For example:

1. on the Account object I created an action to create a new opportunity and prepopulate some fields by going to: Setup -> Object Manager -> Account -> Buttons, Links, and Actions -> New Action.
2. Next add whatever fields you would like to have on the layout that will popup up in LEx when the button is clicked.
3. Then add each predefined field and the default values.

[image: Predefined Fields]

4. Finally add the button to the page layout in the Quick Actions section for Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions.

The button will be available in the top right of the account and when clicked the page layout will popup with the defaults.

[image: Popup New Opportunity]

Comment: Is there a way to call this action from Javascript? There are some validations that I need to make before I can call this action

Comment: @LouisPujol looks like something is in the works according to product manager post on this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM

Comment: Then please vote for my idea  : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNRNQA2

Comment: Note that this only works when the record you're creating has a lookup field to the object you're defining the action on. In my case, we're doing it the other way around (creating a Contact from the Case detail screen, and then linking the created Contact id to the Case in question), and that's not possible using Actions as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 12):

From the Summer '17 Release Notes - [Prepopulate Fields on a Record Create Panel](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_defaultfieldvalues.htm)

> Speed up record creation with prepopulated field values. The sforce.one.createRecord function now includes `defaultFieldValues` (optional) so you can define fields on a record create panel, including fields not displayed on the panel. This change applies to Lightning Experience and the Salesforce1 mobile browser app.
>
> Users must have create access to prepopulated fields. Errors during saving that are caused by field access limitations do not display error messages.

So `defaultFieldValues` will become the official supported mechanism to preset fields with `sforce.one.createRecord`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not documented, so use at your own risk, but you can pass the default values on an attribute named "defaultFieldValues". So for instance, you could create a task and send defaults like this:

```
var evt = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
evt.setParams({
   'entityApiName':'Task',
   'defaultFieldValues': {
      'Status':'Completed'
   },
   'recordTypeId':YOUR_RECORDTYPE_ID_HERE
});

evt.fire();
```

Comment: thanks your solutions works fine. Do you know how to define a callback or catch the save of the new Record? I would like to call an action on my component that fired the event instead of being redirected on the newly created record?

Answer (score 2):

@DanielBallinger's answer is correct. I just want to extend it by an example and show you the most likely pitfalls trying to make it work. Plain and simple, you can use it like this one-liner:

```
sforce.one.createRecord('Contact',null,{ 
    AccountId : "0010Y000007uaVI",  
});
```

**Caution 1:**

The this feature from Summer'17 works only if you put your Visualforce Page to API v40.0 or higher.

**Caution 2:**

Objectnames and Fieldnames are CASE-SENSITiVE! So `contact` is not `Contact` and only `Contact` is correct