# What does the lkid mean? How can I replace it in Lightning?

Tags: apex, lightning

```
  public GE_PW_RiskOverride(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

        RecType=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType');       
        DMname=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CF00N4100000DfLxi');   a0141000006pDoQ
        DMId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CF00N4100000DfLxi_lkid');
```

Answer (score 1):

See the various posts on what lkid is on this forum https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=lkid. It is used as a way of pre-populating a parent object reference when a child record is being created.

It is generally considered a "hack" and constants such as the "CF00N4100000DfLxi" in your example are internal field identifying constants that can vary from org to org.

See [Handling "New" child object creation when making a Visualforce page "Lightning Ready"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150713/handling-new-child-object-creation-when-making-a-visualforce-page-lightning-r) for some information about what can be done in Lightning Experence.