# force:recordEdit for new record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, force-recordedit

There is such great lightning standard component force:recordEdit. It show existing record in standard layout.
Is there any way to show the same layout but for new record (not existing yet). I want to use standard layout to create new record.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm Maybe this can help ? You just need to describe the api name of the object you want to use to create a new record

Comment: I tried it, but it opens new modal and I don't have access to its context. I need to prepopulate some fields for new record. So I want to emulate this createRecord window but with my own custom Action Lightning component.

Comment: You want to prepopulate fields on a create record, the only way I found is using a quick action ( link : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116697/create-record-in-lightning-with-populated-fields ), but it canno't be used inside a lightning component. The quick action is added as a button on the standard record page

Comment: And last but not least, you can customize your own lightning component to create the new record and customize the behavior.. Not standard, but prepopulated fields and can be called from a lightning component