# Auto populate fields on quote creation

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, opportunity, quote

Is there any way to auto populate Quote name field with parent opportunity name when click on new button.I know that It is possible in classic by url hack but how to achieve it in lightning.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[Create record in Lightning with populated fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116697/create-record-in-lightning-with-populated-fields)

The answer here seems to really sum it up in regards to Lightning. I'd look at creating a quick action on the opportunity object, setting up some pre-defined fields (ex. quote name), and then displaying the button on the opportunity layout.

Answer (score 0):

In Lightning, You can launch the record creation page with default values by providing it to URL.

To pre-populate Quote name with Opportunity from related list on Opportunity record,
Create a new list button on Quote and add it on Opportunity related list page layout.
The custom list button url should be like below.

```
/lightning/o/Quote/new?defaultFieldValues=Name={!URLENCODE(Opportunity.Name)}
```

Please check this article for more info.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_useful_custom_buttons_create_record_dfv.htm&type=5